# Can't execute video encoding in ffmpeg-kit-react-native

Tags: react-native, video, ffmpeg, expo, vp9

**Description**

I'm using **React Native and Expo** and trying to convert video from mp4 to vp9 encoded format using **ffmpeg-kit-react-native** package.

I followed installation steps from documentation https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native  .

1. yarn add ffmpeg-kit-react-native
2. In **android/build.gradle**

```
  ext {
      ffmpegKitPackage = "video"
  }
```

3. In **node_modules/ffmpeg-kit-react-native/android/build.gradle**

```
 packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
  }
  rootProject.ext.ffmpegKitPackage = "video"
```

**Expected behavior**

Convert mp4 to vp9 encoded format

**Current behavior**

Throwing error when calling FFmpegKit.execute(`-i ${sourceVideoURI} -c:v libvpx-vp9 ${resultVideoURI}`)

- sourceVideoURI is video URI from expo-image-picker
- resultVideoURI is `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}video/`

**Environment**

- Expo: 45.0.0
- ffmpeg-kit-react-native: 4.5.2
- Platform: Android

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'FFmpegKitReactNativeModule.ffmpegSession')]

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the app on Expo Go? The library cannot run on Expo Go since it uses native codes.
Build a production version of the app and test.